# What is the name of the stack overflow service you can buy/rent and set up your own forum?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

What is the name of the stack overflow service you can buy/rent and set up your own forum?

Comment: related: [Stack Overflow clones](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The service you are referring to where you can have your own Stack Overflow like site is http://stackexchange.com.  Stack Exchange has recently started a private beta.  Stack Exchange will use the same (not sure if it will be 100% or not) engine as the Stack Overflow family sites (Super User, Meta, Server Fault, & Stack Overflow).

Comment: Based on Joel's post a couple days ago, it didn't look like they changed much of anything.

Comment: Obviously no longer true. Stack Exchange 1.0 is dead and buried.

Answer (score 4):

http://stackexchange.com